# Synchronization between BottomNavigation and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I have a personalized Bottom Navigation in my main activity. That means I've created a Layout with 4 buttons on it and made it look like a Bottom Navigation, and each button will run a fragment.

**how can I avoid rebuilding the fragments after they are re-selected?**
**And also how can I retrieve previously executed fragments like a stack when I press the back button? *(Without appearing together)***

Comment: Android introduced ```Navigation component``` which does it for you. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started
Go through the Doc, if you're still not sure let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there another way? @Shahal

Comment: You can try ```TabLayout```.